# UICollectionViewCell height increase incorrectly on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

I am using UICollectionView and using a custom UICollectionViewCell. User created posts showed on the News Feed screen. Based on the length of text, I am increasing the height of cell. But there is strange spacing appears under the "Say Something" text field.

When user enters text by pressing ENTER, it's works perfectly well. If user enters a number of lines without pressing ENTER then issue occurs.

This code works perfectly on iPhone 5 but not on iPhone 6 and 6 plus. I am stuck on this issue since last 1 week. Is this issue related to iPhone 6 and 6 plus only?

I didn't find a relevant question about my problem that's why asking a new question.

```
- (void)configureCell:(NewsFeedObj *)newsFeed{
self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
self.btnPostComment.enabled         = NO;
self.btnPostComment.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:191.0/255.0 green:191.0/255.0 blue:191.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
self.postid                     = newsFeed.postId;
float yPosition = 0;
//*********************Post Username and tagged users setting*********

self.userName.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink; // Automatically detect links when the label text is subsequently changed
self.userName.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.userName.delegate = self; // Delegate methods are called when the user taps on a link (see `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate` protocol)
self.userName.numberOfLines = 4;
self.userName.lineSpacing   = 5;
[self settingUserSectionDetailWithNewsFeed:newsFeed];

CGRect frame = self.userName.frame;

frame.size.height = [self.userName sizeThatFits:self.userName.frame.size].height+3;

self.userName.frame = frame;

//set Time and locatin postion accordint to the name lable.
[self.timeLocationView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.timeLocationView.frame.origin.x, (self.userName.frame.origin.y+self.userName.frame.size.height)+3, self.timeLocationView.frame.size.width, self.timeLocationView.frame.size.height)];
[self.userSection setFrame:CGRectMake(self.userSection.frame.origin.x, self.userSection.frame.origin.y, self.userSection.frame.size.width, self.timeLocationView.frame.origin.y+self.timeLocationView.frame.size.height+5)];
//****************************************user Location setting
if (newsFeed.postLocation.length>0) {
    self.location.hidden    = NO;
    self.locationIconImg.hidden = NO;
    self.location.text = newsFeed.postLocation;
}else{
    self.location.hidden    = YES;
    self.locationIconImg.hidden = YES;
}

//**********************Check Post Spam/Offensive/Or Post is yourself********************
if (newsFeed.postUser.user_id == [ConnectionManager getInstance].userProfile.user_id) {
    [self.btnFlag setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit-report"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else{
    if (newsFeed.postReportFromCurrentUser) {
        if ([newsFeed.postReportFromCurrentUser[@"kind"] isEqualToString:@"offensive"] || [newsFeed.postReportFromCurrentUser[@"kind"] isEqualToString:@"spam"]) {
            [self.btnFlag setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"report_active"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{
            [self.btnFlag setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"report_inactive"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
//post Time setting
self.dateAdded.text             = [self timeLeftSinceDate:[self getDateFromString: newsFeed.postCreatedAt]];
//Post Edit long gesture
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *postTextEdit = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textEditPost:)];
[self.description addGestureRecognizer:postTextEdit];
//***********************************post User profile image setting
NSDictionary *postUserImgDict   = newsFeed.postUser.avatar[@"medium"];
NSString *userImgUrl            = @"";
if (![postUserImgDict[@"url"] isMemberOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    userImgUrl  = postUserImgDict[@"url"];
}
[self.profileImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userImgUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar"]];
[self.profileImage setupImageViewer];
//*************************************Post text setting here
self.description.text           = newsFeed.postBody;
CGSize rect;
if (![newsFeed.postBody isEqualToString:@""]) {
    /*NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0f]};
    NSAttributedString *descString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.description.text attributes:attributes];
    self.description.attributedText = descString;*/

    [self.description setAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0f] forKey:NSFontAttributeName]];
    rect                     =[self.description suggestedFrameSizeToFitEntireStringConstrainedToWidth:self.userSection.frame.size.width-20];
    //rect                       = [self.description sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.userSection.frame.size.width-20, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

    /*if (self.userSection.height>60) {
     [description setFrame:CGRectMake(self.userSection.frame.origin.x+10, self.userSection.frame.origin.y+self.userSection.frame.size.height+10, self.userSection.frame.size.width-20, rect.height+10)];
     }else{
     [description setFrame:CGRectMake(self.userSection.frame.origin.x+10, self.userSection.frame.origin.y+self.userSection.frame.size.height+10, self.userSection.frame.size.width-20, rect.height+10)];
     }*/

    [description setFrame:CGRectMake(self.userSection.frame.origin.x+10, self.userSection.frame.origin.y+self.userSection.frame.size.height+10, self.userSection.frame.size.width-20, rect.height+10)];

    if(IS_IPHONE_5) {
        yPosition = self.description.frame.origin.y+self.description.frame.size.height;
    }
    else {
        yPosition = self.description.frame.origin.y + (rect.height + 10);
    }

}else{
    yPosition = self.userSection.frame.origin.y+self.userSection.frame.size.height+10;
}
//*************************************************************************
//post Image setting here

if(![newsFeed.postImageUrl isMemberOfClass:[NSNull class]] && ![newsFeed.postImageUrl isEqualToString:@""]){

    [self.postedImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newsFeed.postImageUrl] placeholderImage:nil];
    self.postedImage.hidden = NO;
    self.postedImage.frame      = CGRectMake(0, yPosition, self.postedImage.frame.size.width, self.postedImage.frame.size.height);
    yPosition = self.postedImage.frame.origin.y+self.postedImage.frame.size.height;

}else{
    self.postedImage.hidden = YES;
}
//***************************Rating Section ************************************
self.ratingSection.frame         = CGRectMake(self.ratingSection.frame.origin.x, yPosition, self.ratingSection.frame.size.width, self.ratingSection.frame.size.height);

yPosition = self.ratingSection.frame.origin.y+self.ratingSection.frame.size.height;
//***************************RatingCOunt Section ************************************
self.countSection.frame         = CGRectMake(self.countSection.frame.origin.x, yPosition, self.countSection.frame.size.width, self.countSection.frame.size.height);
if (newsFeed.postRatingAction.count>0) {

    self.lblAwesome.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld .",(long)[newsFeed.postRatingAction[0] integerValue]];
    self.lblWhatevs.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld .",(long)[newsFeed.postRatingAction[1] integerValue]];
    self.lblNoBueno.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld .",(long)[newsFeed.postRatingAction[2] integerValue]];
    if (newsFeed.postReactionFromCurrentUser.count>0) {
        if ([newsFeed.postReactionFromCurrentUser[@"kind"] isEqualToString:@"awesome"]) {
            self.btnAwesome.selected = YES;
            self.btnWhatEvs.selected = NO;
            self.btnNoBueno.selected = NO;
        }else if ([newsFeed.postReactionFromCurrentUser[@"kind"] isEqualToString:@"whatevs"]) {
            self.btnAwesome.selected = NO;
            self.btnWhatEvs.selected = YES;
            self.btnNoBueno.selected = NO;
        }else if ([newsFeed.postReactionFromCurrentUser[@"kind"] isEqualToString:@"nobueno"]){
            self.btnAwesome.selected = NO;
            self.btnWhatEvs.selected = NO;
            self.btnNoBueno.selected = YES;
        }
    }else{
        self.btnAwesome.selected = NO;
        self.btnWhatEvs.selected = NO;
        self.btnNoBueno.selected = NO;
    }
}
yPosition = self.countSection.frame.origin.y+self.countSection.frame.size.height;

//***************************Comment Section ************************************
//if comment against post not empty
if (newsFeed.commentsArray.count>0) {
    self.commentSectionContainer.hidden = NO;
    float commenty=0;
    self.lblComments.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)newsFeed.commentsArray.count];
    for (postComment *comment in newsFeed.commentsArray) {
        commentSection *commentView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TextComment"
                                                                     owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        commentView.editCommentView.txtComment.delegate = self;
        commentView.tag             = 1000+[newsFeed.commentsArray indexOfObject:comment];
        commentView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [commentView.profileImg setupImageViewer];
        commentView.profileName.text = comment.UserName;
        [self commentNameSettingWithLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)commentView.profileName];
        CGSize stringsize = [comment.UserName sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
        [commentView.profileName setFrame:CGRectMake(commentView.profileName.frame.origin.x, commentView.profileName.frame.origin.y, stringsize.width+5, commentView.profileName.frame.size.height)];
        commentView.profileName.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        commentView.lblComentTime.frame = CGRectMake(commentView.profileName.frame.origin.x+commentView.profileName.frame.size.width, commentView.lblComentTime.frame.origin.y, commentView.lblComentTime.frame.size.width, commentView.lblComentTime.frame.size.height);
        //Set comment time here
        commentView.lblComentTime.text  = [self timeLeftSinceDate:[self getDateFromString:comment.created_at]];

        [commentView.profileImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:comment.UserProfileImg] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar"]];

        if (comment.isEditComment) {
            //Add edit view for edit comment

            commentView.editCommentView.txtComment.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
            commentView.editCommentView.txtComment.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
            commentView.lblCommentText.hidden  = YES;
            commentView.editCommentView.hidden = NO;
            commentView.editCommentView.txtComment.editable = YES;
            commentView.lblCommentText.text       = comment.text;
            commentView.editCommentView.txtComment.text = comment.text;
            CGSize comentRect                     =[commentView.lblCommentText suggestedFrameSizeToFitEntireStringConstrainedToWidth:commentView.frame.size.width];

            [commentView.editCommentView.txtComment setFrame:CGRectMake(commentView.editCommentView.txtComment.frame.origin.x, commentView.editCommentView.txtComment.frame.origin.y, commentView.editCommentView.txtComment.frame.size.width, comentRect.height+15)];
            [commentView.editCommentView setFrame:CGRectMake(commentView.editCommentView.frame.origin.x, commentView.editCommentView.frame.origin.y, commentView.editCommentView.frame.size.width, commentView.editCommentView.txtComment.frame.origin.y+commentView.editCommentView.txtComment.frame.size.height)];
            [commentView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.sharingSection.frame.origin.x, commenty, self.frame.size.width, commentView.editCommentView.frame.origin.y+commentView.editCommentView.frame.size.height+10)];
            commentView.editCommentView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            if(commentView.editCommentView.txtComment.isEditable){
                [commentView.editCommentView.txtComment becomeFirstResponder];
            }

        }else{
            commentView.lblCommentText.hidden  = NO;
            commentView.editCommentView.hidden = YES;
            commentView.lblCommentText.text = comment.text;
            CGSize comentRect                     =[commentView.lblCommentText suggestedFrameSizeToFitEntireStringConstrainedToWidth:commentView.frame.size.width-20];
            //coment Frame setting
            [commentView.lblCommentText setFrame:CGRectMake(commentView.lblCommentText.frame.origin.x, commentView.lblCommentText.frame.origin.y, commentView.lblCommentText.frame.size.width, comentRect.height)];
            [commentView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.sharingSection.frame.origin.x, commenty, self.frame.size.width, commentView.lblCommentText.frame.origin.y+commentView.lblCommentText.frame.size.height+10)];
        }
        commentView.userInteractionEnabled   = YES;
        if (comment.commentUserid == [ConnectionManager getInstance].userProfile.user_id) {
            //long Press for edit or deleted comment
            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *cmttap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(commentEditOrDelete:)];
            [commentView addGestureRecognizer:cmttap];
        }

        commenty = commentView.frame.origin.y+commentView.frame.size.height;
        commentView.sepratorView.frame = CGRectMake(0, commentView.frame.size.height-1, commentView.frame.size.width, 1);
        [self.commentSectionContainer addSubview:commentView];
        self.commentSectionContainer.frame = CGRectMake(self.commentSectionContainer.frame.origin.x, yPosition, self.frame.size.width, commentView.frame.origin.y+commentView.frame.size.height);
        [self setCommentLabelFontwitLabel:commentView.lblCommentText];
    }

    yPosition = self.commentSectionContainer.frame.origin.y+self.commentSectionContainer.frame.size.height;
}else{
    self.commentSectionContainer.hidden = YES;
    self.lblComments.text = @"0";
}
//***************************Post Comment Section ************************************
self.txtComentView.text             = @"";
//self.postCommentSection.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
//self.postCommentSection.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

self.postCommentSection.frame       = CGRectMake(self.postCommentSection.frame.origin.x, yPosition, self.postCommentSection.frame.size.width, self.postCommentSection.frame.size.height);
yPosition                       = self.postCommentSection.frame.origin.y+self.postCommentSection.frame.size.height;


self.cellTotalHeight = yPosition;
[self setTweetLabelFont];
```

}

Comment: Probably this has something to do with your autolayout. Are you using size classes?

Comment: I am not using auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem by creating 3 different xib files for iPhone 5, 6 and 6 Plus.